# Get file path and URL for file in temp directory

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, nsbundle

I'm trying to get the file path of a file called "temp.pdf" which is located in the NSTemporaryDirectory folder (I've checked, the file exists).

I use this:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"temp" ofType:@"pdf" inDirectory:NSTemporaryDirectory()];
```

I've tried with:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"temp.pdf" ofType:@"" inDirectory:NSTemporaryDirectory()];
```

And:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"temp" ofType:@"pdf"];
```

But it seems that it doesn't work, return value is always null.

How can I access the file path?

Answer (score 132, accepted):

[`NSTemporaryDirectory()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1409211-nstemporarydirectory?language=objc) provides a full path to the temporary directory. Instead of using your `mainBundle` have you tried

```
NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp.pdf"];
```

If you need a URL instead, do this:

```
NSURL *furl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp.pdf"]];
```

Comment: OK, when I do that, I want to use filepath with [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:filepath]; I've made [NSURL urlWithString:filepath], but Xcode says : "Invalid scheme (null).  Only the file scheme is supported."

Comment: Try `NSURL *furl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp.pdf"]];`

Comment: What if we want to return all pdf files in temp directory??

Answer (score 14):

**Swift 2.0**

```
let tmpDirURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSTemporaryDirectory(),isDirectory: true)
let fileURL = tmpDirURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("stuff").URLByAppendingPathExtension("gif")
print("FilePath: \(fileURL.path)")
```

Answer (score 4):

**For Swift 3.0**

```
var fileUrl: URL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory())
fileUrl.appendPathComponent("foo")
fileUrl.appendPathExtension("bar")
```